# Generating report from rdlc xml string

Tags: c#, reporting-services, reportviewer, rdlc, localreport

I'm facing an issue when generating reports.

I should generate report dynamically using all data from database for it (source name and rdlc report that stores as xml string)

So I solved problem next way:

1. Create local rdlc file with report xml string;
2. Set path to the file;

   ```
   var rViewer = new ReportViewer();
   rViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = @"Path to the generated xml rdlc file";
   var dataSource = new ReportDataSource("DataSourceName", data);
   rViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(dataSource);
   ```

Could I specify in the code-behind directly Report XML String instead of generating the rdlc file and set path to it? Could you recommend a better way?

Thank You

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, You can provide it a StringReader object using LoadReportDefinition like so,

```
private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    NMBS.ViewModels.ViewModelReport Report = (Session["CurrentReport"] as NMBS.ViewModels.ViewModelReport);
ReportViewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
ReportViewer.PageCountMode = PageCountMode.Actual;

// Set report specifics.
ReportViewer.LocalReport.DisplayName = Report.Name;
ReportViewer.LocalReport.LoadReportDefinition(new System.IO.StringReader(Report.Definition));
foreach (ReportParameter Param in Report.Parameters)
{
    ReportViewer.LocalReport.SetParameters(Param);
}
foreach (ReportDataSource Rds in Report.Data)
{
    //Load Report Data.
    ReportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(Rds);
}
ReportViewer.CurrentPage = Report.CurrentPage;
ReportViewer.Width = Report.Width;

// Refresh the reports.
ReportViewer.LocalReport.Refresh();
}
```

Where Report.Defintion is the String containing the XML of the Report's Definition.